# Number Theory: Prove that $p|m-n$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Assume $p$ is an odd prime number, $\displaystyle q = \frac{3p-5}{2}$ and $$ S_q = \frac{1}{2.3.4} + \frac {1}{5.6.7} + ... + \frac{1}{q(q+1)(q+2)}$$.
>   If $\displaystyle \frac{1}{p} - 2S_q = \frac{m}{n}$ and $m$ and $n$ are two integers, Prove that $p\  | \ m-n$.

Any hints how to start the proof?

Comment: @BarryCipra Oh I see, the problem is that I took the index from $1$ instead of $2$.

Comment: Shouldn't the second term in $S_q$ be $\frac{1}{3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5}$ instead of the posted $\frac{1}{5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7}\,$?

Comment: $$ (n^2 + 3 n - 4)\over (12 (n + 1) (n + 2))$$ Used WA this time.

Comment: @dxiv No, it is meant to be that order. Notice that $q+1=3\frac{p-1}{2}$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Right, I misread it. Removing previous hint which doesn't really help in this case.

Comment: Given the errors that have come and gone in comments, I'd say the OP has asked a good question!

Comment: In fact $p^2|m-n$ if $p\geq 5$.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with the identity
$$
\frac{1}{(3n-1)(3n)(3n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3n-1}+\frac{1}{3n}+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n}.
$$
Using this:
$$
\begin{align*}
S_q &= \sum_{n=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\left(\frac{1}{3n-1}+\frac{1}{3n}+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\bigg]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=2}^{(3p-1)/2}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{n=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(-1+\sum_{k=(p-1)/2}^{(3p-1)/2}\frac{1}{k}\right).
\end{align*}
$$
Can you take it from there? You might find [Wolstenholme's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem) useful.